# Differences between Two-Grid Correction and V-Cycle Scheme

Tags: multigrid

I found in *A Multigrid Tutorial: Second Edition* by *William L. Briggs‏, Van Emden Henson‏, Steve F.* ([here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Multigrid_Tutorial/ahklDynzz8cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=A%20Multigrid%20Tutorial:%20Second%20Edition&printsec=frontcover)) the following Schemes:

Two-Grid Correction Scheme, p. 37:

[image]

And V-Cycle Scheme, p. 40

[image]

I want to check that I understood it correctly, Two-Grid is just a multigrid scheme when the algorithm going one level coarser. It's useful for cases where it possible to solve $A^{2h}e^{2h}=r^{2h}$ equation, otherwise it implemented recursively which basically creating the V-Cycle. Did I understand it right? Is there any additional advantages and disadvantages of Two-Grid Vs. V-Cycle?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know in which case to use Two-Grid and in which V-Cycle. Any human based comments are welcome.

Comment: Two-grid is the most basic multi-grid scheme, yes. If you go down to a coarse level, and go all the way back up again, that is a V-cycle. There are other types of cycles like W-cycle, F-cycle, etc.